# Break Function without return

Tags: julia

I have a function

```
function foo(a)
    if a > 5 
        a = 5
    end
    some_more_code
end
```

If the `if`-statement is `true` I would like to end the function but I don't want to return anything - to change the value of `a` is all I need.

How do I do that?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to achieve. Do you want to modify `a` in-place?

Comment: Yes, I do want to modify `a` in place.

Comment: That may not be possible: only mutable datastructures can be modified in-place. In your example `a` is an `Int` which is immutable, thus can't be modified in-place in any way. What you could do is to wrap your variable in a mutable container, like an array or a `Ref`, but this add much more complexity. Think better about what you want to do

Comment: You're right. In my actual code a *is* a mutable structure. Wanted to do it like this to make it a minimal example. Either way - this discussion is totally unrelated to the actual question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write (note that I have also changed the syntax of function definition to make it more standard for Julia style):

```
function foo(a)
    if a > 5 
        a = 5
        return
    end
    # some_more_code
end
```

Just use the `return` keyword without any expression following it. To be precise in such cases Julia returns `nothing` value of type `Nothing` from a function (which is not printed in REPL and serves to signal that you did not want to return anything from a function).

Note though that the value of `a` will be only changed locally (within the scope of the function), so that outside of the function it will be unchanged:

```
julia> function foo(a)
           if a > 5 
               a = 5
               return
           end
           # some_more_code
       end
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> x = 10

julia> foo(x)

julia> x
10
```

In order to make the change *visible* outside of the function you have to make `a` to be some kind of container. A typical container for such cases is `Ref`:

```
julia> function foo2(a)
           if a[] > 5 
               a[] = 5
               return
           end
           # some_more_code
       end
foo2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> x = Ref(10)
Base.RefValue{Int64}(10)

julia> foo2(x)

julia> x[]
5
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the answer. And thanks for changing the syntax. My version was habits coming from `R`. I will change it in the question as well.

Comment: the syntax `f = function ...` works but it creates an anonymous function which is binded to a variable `f`, see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#man-anonymous-functions-1. Sometimes this is useful (e.g. when you would like to bind a completely different function to name `f` later, but this is a rare use case). Usually it is better to define a function in a standard way.